# PC connects to wifi on Channel 11 but iMac/iPhone can't. All work fine on Channel 5. Why? I'm not in a busy area

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, imac

As follows

- Windows PC connects to wifi (Netgear DGN2000) on router's default    Channel 11 fine.
- iMac makes a connection over wifi on Channel 11 and gets IP address, subnet, router address but can't ping router or open admin page on it.
- iPhone 4S completely fails to connect to same router on Channel 11.  Just hangs.
- iMac works fine when plugged in to Ethernet socket on router but we don't want wires trailing across the house.
- iMac and iPhone both connect to a different router (DG834) on Channel 11 fine. Sadly in a different town.
- when I switch the DGN2000 over to Channel 5 ... PC, iMac and iPhone all connect fine and can see the outside world as normal. (I chose Channel 5 at random. Using InSSIDer I see that most channels are empty.)
- I am not in a busy area - there is just one other wifi available here (it's a quiet street) and I can connect to that fine from any machine.

Any ideas why? Is one other wifi network enough to clash on a wifi channel?

Also, is there any rule to guide choice of alternative channel?

I've searched for similar questions and believe I'm not asking a dupe.

iMac OS X Lion. iPhone iOS 5.1.  PC Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of wireless connection are we talking about (a, b, g, n) ? I know your router is capable of wireless N, but is that what your setting up?

Depending on which your trying to get the devices working with there are overlapping channels and non overlapping channels.

> Is one other wifi network enough to clash on a wifi channel?

Yes it is possible that someone using the same channel as you can cause issues.

> Also, is there any rule to guide choice of alternative channel?

Read these articles and try to select a different channel that is more compatible and not close to channel overlaps:

- http://www.pastebay.net/1068816 (I couldn't post more then 2 links so I posted them on pastebay)

You can also use tools to help you discover networks in your area and learn what they are using to help diagnose things. Like Fing which has windows, mac and : http://overlooksoft.com/

Note also that some devices have issues with wireless N and you may need to drop it down to something more compatible with all your devices.